# Top 5 moves using chess.engine.SimpleEngine

Tags: python, chess, python-chess, stockfish

I'm having trouble with the engine encapsulation of python-chess, I would like to use the Stockfish function `top = stockfish.get_top_moves(5)` but it seems like there is no way to do it using chess.engine.simpleEngine, do you have any advices?

I already tried getting all the result and then keeping just the top 5 move of the last evaluation using this piece of code:

`self.engine.analysis(self.board, chess.engine.Limit(depth=18), multipv=5, root_moves = move_actions)`

but it's tricky since the function is asyncronous and I'm integrating with other function that are not changeable I cannot make it asynchronous.

I'm going crazy trying to make it work, thanks to everybody.

Comment: Please provide some of your code that would actually run, to show how you define `stockfish` using `chess.engine.simpleEngine`. What part of your code are you having trouble with? Calling an asynchronous function from synchronous code and awaiting the result? Creating an instance of a class in the imported package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async object returned by that function is empty at first; you can wait until it is done by calling its `.wait()` method. Instead, if you don't want the async parts of `engine.analysis`, you can call `engine.analyse` which blocks until done and returns the result more directly. Both functions work to get the top 5 moves as you requested. Here is an example script:

```
import chess
import chess.engine

stockfish = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("<file path to engine>")

# Using engine.analysis
analysis_result = stockfish.analysis(chess.Board(), limit=chess.engine.Limit(depth=18), multipv=5)
analysis_result.wait()  # This is the missing step
analysed_variations = analysis_result.multipv

# Or instead using engine.analyse
analysed_variations = stockfish.analyse(chess.Board(), limit=chess.engine.Limit(depth=18), multipv=5)

# Either way you now have a dict of results, with moves under "pv"
top_five_moves = [variation["pv"][0] for variation in analysed_variations]
```